# How to query documents using “_id” field in Java mongodb driver without using the collection name?

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my document, that i want to get.

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5747f303631e1e261019914d"},
 "school": "aaa", "name": "Kamal", "likes": 200}
```

I want to get this only by passing its `_id` without giving its collection.

```
public DBObject findDocumentById(String id) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    DBObject dbObj = collection.findOne(query);
    return dbObj;
}
```

As I am searching for different documents in different collections, I don't want to say in which collection does the `_id` belongs. So without saying `collection.findOne(query)`.

How to get the documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mention what is the Collection. But you can try this.

```
for(String collectionName : mongoOperation.getCollectionNames()){

    DBCollection collection = mongoOperation.getCollection(collectionName);

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));

    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);

    if(cursor.hasNext()){
        //match
        //do something
        break;
    }

}
```